# Is there a way to use something other than a header tag to indicate a header in jQuery Mobile collapsible block?

Tags: jquery-mobile

According to the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/content/content-collapsible.html), after marking a div with data-role="collapsible" there needs to be a header tag (h1 - h6) so that jQuery Mobile will turn it into the header of the collapsible block.

My question is, is there other way to indicate the header? Something like: data-role="collapsible-header"?

Comment: I suspect not. I'm curious why. What do you have against header tags?

Comment: I have nothing against them. Just the requirements I got for the visible part of the collapsible block, didn't make sense to have all in a header tag, semantically speaking. Also, I didn't want to write the extra CSS for the full site version to avoid the boldness and other header specific styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a legend rather than h#

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it did helped me avoid the formatting of header tags without generating extra CSS. Thanks!