# Recipes to inject complex structures within a collapsible header in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Reading the documentation of jQuery Mobile, to create a collapsible element you need to use `h1-h6` or `legend` elements.

Since in the header section I need to display different information (a title, a date and an amount) I would like to know if it is correct to include a complex structure within an `h#` tag. In other words, will this a valid HTML structure?

According to this discussion [Is there a way to use something other than a header tag to indicate a header in jQuery Mobile collapsible block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521256/is-there-a-way-to-use-something-other-than-a-header-tag-to-indicate-a-header-in) a legend element could be ok but I'm not using a form.

Any recipes?

Comment: HTML5 specifies that [phrasing tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) are ok inside a header tag. So `span` and `a` are your friends, `div` not. Regarding other elements denoting a header - check what markup JQM applies to a header, especially `role` (not data-role) and `aria-tags`. Add the same to an element of your liking, plus the appropriate ui classes (I guess `ui-header ui-bar-your_theme` and you have a header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking from the point of **`HTML`** that that is not a valid **`HTML`**.

Of course you can disregard that. Point is, if jQuery Mobile developers don't care about valid **`HTML`**, you also don't need to care.

Let me prove it to you, before enhancement standard collapsible looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h6>Heading</h6>
    <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
```

After enhancement it looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-collapsed">
    <h6 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c" data-mini="false">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Heading
                <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
            </span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
        </a>
    </h6>
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">

        <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see **`h6`** is filled with additional content. So feel free and change whatever you want.

Comment: @Gajotres: not to bother but last time I checked HTML5 allows phrasing content inside header tag. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/h1.html), [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/terminology.html#phrasing-content) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html-markup-20101019/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing). So as far as collapsibles are concerned JQM is perfectly valid.